# ValueError:Gas estimation failed:'execution reverted'.This transaction will likely revert.If you wish to broadcast,you must set the gas limit manually

Tags: solidity, python, revert

I get this error when trying to my deploy .sol contract: "ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually. "

Any help would be welcomed. Thank you. The account has a balance: account balance: 97946875117500000000

I deploy with this line of code : convert = converter.deploy({"from": account})

My code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.6 <0.9.0;

contract converter {

    struct rprices {
        uint256 _epochId;
        uint256[2] _ftsoIndices;
        uint256[2] _prices;
        uint256[2] _random;
    }
    rprices[] public rprice;

    constructor() {
        converter1();
    }

    function converter1()
        public
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256[2] memory,
            uint256[2] memory,
            uint256[2] memory
        )
    {
        rprice.push(
            rprices(
                2342,
                [
                    2323423445345345345345343423423223234234453453453453453434234232,
                    22342323423445345343453453534534534342342322343545345345345345345323423342342
                ],
                [
                    22342323423445345343453453534534534342342322343545345345345345345323423342342,
                    22342323423445345343453453534534534342342322343545345345345345345323423342342
                ],
                [
                    22342323423445345343453453534534534342342322343545345345345345345323423342342,
                    22342323423445345343453453534534534342342322343545345345345345345323423342342
                ]
            )
        );

        return (
            rprice[2]._epochId,
            rprice[2]._ftsoIndices,
            rprice[2]._prices,
            rprice[2]._random
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the exact logic of your smart contract but the revert is caused by accessing an element out of bound from your `rprice` array.
When you deploy the contract, at the beginning `rprice` has 0 element, and after `rprice.push(...` in the function `converter1 ()`, `rprice` now has 1 element. So the fix is at the return statement of converter1:

```
function converter1() 
  ... 
  ...
  ...

   return (
        rprice[0]._epochId,
        rprice[0]._ftsoIndices,
        rprice[0]._prices,
        rprice[0]._random
    );
```

Because rprice has only 1 element, you must access it with index 0 (`rprice[0]`).